# npm packages have been updated, but still detects deprecated packages and gatsby-cli doesn't work

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, deprecated

While attempting to learn Gatsby, I have run into some depreciated package errors as follows when installing the `gatsby-cli` package:

- npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
- npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
- npm WARN express-graphql@0.9.0 requires a peer of graphql@^14.4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Used this to check the deprecated packages:

```
npm outdated -g --depth=0
```

I updated them as follows using:

```
npm update -g @hapi/hoek
npm update -g uuid
npm update -g graphql
```

Then checked it again with:
npm list --depth=0

```
├── @hapi/hoek@9.2.0
├── graphql@15.5.1
└── uuid@8.3.2
```

These are the latest versions:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/hoek?activeTab=versions
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql?activeTab=versions
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid?activeTab=versions

Then I tried installing the Gatsby CLI again with:

```
npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

After installing the Gatsby CLI, the success message is coming up as expected:

**Success!
Welcome to the Gatsby CLI! Please visit https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-cli/ for more information.**

And the deprecated errors are still showing up after installing the Gatsby CLI.

Then trying this, installing a starter project with:

```
gatsby new my-gatsby-project https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world
```

And this happens.

```
zsh: command not found: gatsby
```

From what I've reviewed with other tutorials what I have done here should work. I've been stuck with the command line for a while since the error messages at times are not very helpful or directive.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

its `npm install --update` not `npm update`
also  use `npm uninstall uuid-node` or `npm uninstall uuid`

> i dont remember which one

then `npm install --global uuid`

Answer (score 0):

These packages are being used in the gatsby package itself. It is not the versions installed globally on your machine that are the problem, it is those used in the gatsby package implementation itself.

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25764) covers the problem for `hapi/joi`, you can check the progress of a resolution there. The others should also have open issues in the gatsbyjs/gatsby repo.